# Dual of $C(X)$ with the compact open topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a completely regular space and let $C_k(X)$ be the space of all continuous functions with the compact-open topology. If $X$ is completely metrizable, is the strong dual $C(X)^*$ the strong projective limit of the spaces $C(K)$, where $K$ is a compact subset of $K$?

Comment: Related questions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145215/dual-of-the-space-of-continuous-functions and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105147/measure-theory-treatment-geared-toward-the-riesz-representation-theorem

Comment: No. By the references mentioned by  András Bátkai, $\mathcal{C}(X)^*$ can be identified with the space of (Radon) measures on $X$ with compact support. This space maps by restriction to each $\mathcal{C}(K)^*$, hence to their projective limit, but the latter map is not surjective: the family of Lebesgue measures on compacts of $\mathbb{R}$ does not come from a compactly supported measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @abx, but if you take such a measure $\mu$ (supported on the whole real line), how do you guarantee that $\int f d \mu$ is finite for every (unbounded) continuous function?

Comment: I don't. This is why the answer is negative.

Comment: @abx, sorry I don't understand. What are Lebesgue measures for you?

Comment: Take for instance the discrete space $X:=\mathbb{N}$. Then $C(X)$ is the projective limit $\displaystyle{\lim_\leftarrow } $ of the embeddings $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, that is the Fréchet space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ with the product topology, and this is also the projective limit of $C(K)^*$ for $K\Subset\mathbb{N}$. On the other side,  $C(X)^*$ is the space $c_c$ of compactly supported sequences, that is the inductive limit $\displaystyle{\lim_\rightarrow } $ of the $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, topologized by all seminorms on it, a complete, non metrizable LCTVS.

Comment: @Tomek Kania: The restriction of the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}$, what else?