# Weak convergence (probability theory) and weak* convergence (functional analysis)

Tags: pr.probability

Let $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of probability measures on $\mathbb R$ with the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^p)$. That is, $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ can be considered as a sequence in the Banach space $\mathcal M(\mathbb R^p)$ of all finite signed Borel measures on $\mathbb R^p$ equipped with the total variation norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\text{TV}}$.

In probability theory, the sequence $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is called weakly convergent to some probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^p)$ iff $$\left\vert\int f\,\mathrm d\mu_n - \int f\,\mathrm d\mu\right\vert$$ converges to zero for every $f\in\mathcal C_b(\mathbb R^p)$, where $\mathcal C_b(\mathbb R^p)$ denote the space of all real-valued bounded, continuous functions on $\mathbb R^p$.

In functional analysis, a sequence $(\phi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $(\mathcal C(\mathbb R^p))^*$ is called weak*ly convergent to some $\phi\in(\mathcal C(\mathbb R^p))^*$ iff $$\left\vert\phi_n(f) - \phi(f)\right\vert$$ converges to zero for each $f\in\mathcal C(\mathbb R^p)$. It is known that $(\mathcal C_b(\mathbb R^p))^*\simeq \mathcal M(\mathbb R^p)$ (c.f. [the dual space of C(X) (X is noncompact metric space)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89274/the-dual-space-of-cx-x-is-noncompact-metric-space)). So for each $\nu\in\mathcal M(\mathbb R^p)$ there is a $\varphi\in(\mathcal C_b(\mathbb R^p))^*$ such that $$\varphi(f) = \int f\,\mathrm d\nu$$ for $f\in\mathcal C_b(\mathbb R^p)$.

So the sequence $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is weak*ly convergent to some some $\mu\in\mathcal M(\mathbb R^p)$ iff $$\left\vert\int f\,\mathrm d\mu_n - \int f\,\mathrm d\mu\right\vert$$ converges to zero for every $f\in\mathcal C_b(\mathbb R^p)$, and the two definitions coincide.

**Note:** My original question had an error (I mixed up the duals) which caused confusion. In fact, after resolving the error, the question has been answered.

Comment: You do not describe the weak$^*$-convergence on the spaces of signed measures but the weak convergence. The weak topology  is strictly finer than the weak$^*$-topology.

Comment: What is $\int \phi d\mu$? Is it $(\phi,\mu)$ in the functional analysis sense?

Comment: You got the duals and preduals mixed up: it's really $C(K)^*=\mathcal M$, not the other way around.

Comment: And yes, on a compact space, the probabilist's weak convergence is exactly the functional analyst's weak $*$ convergence.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I am very confused now: we are looking at sequences in $\mathcal M$. The dual of $\mathcal M$ is $\mathcal C_b(\mathcal K)$, no? The comment of @ChristianRemling is suggesting that there is a mistake, but what's then the dual of $\mathcal M$? Or did I completely mess up duals and pre-duals?

Comment: @SydAmerikaner: No, the dual of $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^p)$ is not $\mathcal{C}_b(\mathcal{K})$. The dual of $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^p)$ contains, e.g., all bounded measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$, among further elements. (I don't know an explicit description of the entire dual space.)

Comment: Please also note that the inclusion $\mathcal{C}_b(\mathbb{R}^p) \subset \mathcal{C}_b(\mathcal{K})$ in your post is a bit misleading: (i) You don't need the subscript $b$ at the second space since continuous functions on a compact space are automatically bounded. (ii) One does not really have an inclusion, but a canonical mapping from one space to the other. (iii) This mapping is actually an isomorphism - so if you wish to identify the domain and image of this isomorphism, then you get an equality between $\mathcal{C}_b(\mathbb{R}^p)$ and $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{K})$, not just an inclusion.

Comment: In fact, I know see that I mixed up the duals. I edited the question (which now no longer is a question as removing the error resolves my confusion) accordingly. Thank you everyone!

Comment: With respect, there is still some confusion.  In the compact  case, the dual of the Banach space $C(K)$ is the space of bounded Radon measures.  This has a natural Banach space structure but this is not the one used by probabilists and, as pointed out in a comment its dual is larger then $C(K)$.  One can make a case for considering it as a complete lcs with the topology of uniform convergence on the compacta of $C(K)$--this is the structure which is used (implicitly) in probability  and its dual can be identified with $C(K)$.  The convergent sequences  are precisely the ones you mention.

Comment: The situation can be extended to the non compact case--the short version is that we have the same facts if we consider the   duality between the space $C^b(S)$  with the strict topology (decidedly not as a Banach space since the dual then is the space of finitely additive bounded measures,   not the Radon measures) and the space of bounded Radon measures with the finest locally convex topology which agrees  with the weak topology induced by $C^b(S)$ on the uniformly tight subsets.

Answer (score 5):

This is just a comment (but I am not entitled) which might help to illuminate the situation.  In the case of a compact space $K$, all is clear--$C(K)$ is a Banach space, its dual is the space of bounded, Radon measures and the weak $\ast $ topology in the functional analytic sense coincides with the standard notion for convergence of measure (and both can be restricted to the probability measures of course).  The situation for the non compact case has also been studied in detail, both for a locally compact space $S$  and, more generally, completely regular spaces.  The natural replacement for $C(K)$, at first sight, is the Banach space  $C^b(S)$ but this was soon recognised to be inadequate (it doesn´t distinguish between $S$ and its Stone-Cech compactification  and its dual is too large since it contains measures on $S$ which are only finitely additive).

It was soon realised that this situation could be remedied, if one was prepared to leave the comfort zone of Banach spaces and use more esoteric tools of locally convex theory.  One of the most prominent examples is a paper of R.C. Buck (1955) who introduced the so-called strict topology in the case of locally compact $S$.  This was defined using weighted seminorms and is a complete lc structure on $C^b(S)$  for which the dual space is precisely the space of bounded Radon measures.  This was soon extended to general completely regular spaces where the strict topology is most succinctly described as the finest lc topology which agrees with compact convergence on the unit ball.  This allows a natural extension to the non-compact case which shows how the measure theoretical and  functional analytic approaches coincide just as in the compact one.

Added after OP´s comment on duality.  Thus we have the following situation: a locally convex space $C^b(S)$ of functions on a topological space whose dual is identifiable with  a space of measures, the bounded Radon measures.  On the latter we have two kinds of convergence,  weak convergence (in a dual space) and the probabilist´s concept of convergence and these coincide.

In fact, the above duality is perfectly symmetric--the space of measures is, as described above, the dual of the lc space $C^b(S)$ with the strict topology and $C^b(S)$ can also be regarded as the dual of the space of measures. However, for this to hold we have to use the right choice of structures, in the compact case the symmetric duality between Banach and Waelbroeck spaces, in the non compact one between Saks and CoSaks spaces.  These are too complex to describe here but they are discussed  in detail in the monographs  "Functors and Categories of Banach spaces" and  "Saks Spaces and Applications to Functional Analysis".